# how to send the data every 5 minutes in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have a project WebAPI, I want to provide data every 5 minutes or so to the client:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

namespace MyWebApi.Controllers
{
    public class EventController : ApiController
    {
        public string Get()
        {
            var id = Guid.NewGuid();
            string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(id, new IsoDateTimeConverter());
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the error or problem!

Comment: WebAPI way to send data every 5 minutes

Comment: What you have tried so far!! Your question does not show any research efforts for your problem. If you want to send data from WebAPI to client, see something like [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)

Comment: HTTP is request/response. You need to use something like polling or WebSockets. +1 on SignalR, which uses WebSockets when available and has [fallbacks](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr) if WebSockets isn't available.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use C# timer. You can create a static object and set time interval is 5 mins.
Here is an example I got from http://www.dotnetperls.com/timer

```
public static class TimerExample
{

    static Timer _timer;
    static List<DateTime> _l;
    public static List<DateTime> DateList
    {
        get
        {
            if (_l == null)
            {
                Start(); // Start the timer
            }
            return _l;
        }
    }
    static void Start()
    {
        _l = new List<DateTime>();
        _timer = new Timer(300000); // Set up the timer for 5 mins

        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
        _timer.Enabled = true; 
    }
    static void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Add event here
    }
}
```